# A psychic science fiction book I read in the 80's an MIT rock star that sings to a flower and it sings back

Tags: story-identification, psychic, evolution

I read that story in the 80s, although it might be older.

It starts with a young genius who becomes a rock star. He's out practicing in a field, singing to a flower, when he realizes that he's sensitive enough to hear the flowers' vibrational reaction.

Next, a major city in the USA and one in the USSR are threatened with annihilation if the super powers don't disarm their nuclear and psychic weapons.

A major and a woman are consciously elevated when they find the singer's body in a coma at a (pre?) cryo facility.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a duplicate of this question:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85708/telepath-pretending-to-be-in-coma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telepath pretending to be in coma](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85708/telepath-pretending-to-be-in-coma)

Comment: @NeoDarwin, we don't propose duplicates for story ID questions unless it can be confirmed by both OPs. This is usually done by accepting an answer. If you think they're similar, you can make an answer here stating the book, referencing the other question. If that answer is accepted the questions are then that's good.

Comment: Potentially better duplicate target at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192518/70s-80s-book-cold-war-psychic-superweapons. (Note to Rosemarie: All this "duplicate" stuff doesn't mean your question is improper -- it's just site administration to help future searchers by connecting questions about the same story. Welcome to the site.)

Answer (score 7):

**[Star Fire](https://books.google.com/books?id=_mxuDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22It%20had%20happened%20in%20a%20country%20meadow%20while%20he%20was%20at%20work%20on%20composing%20a%20new%20song.%20The%20words%20resisted%20for%20a%20while%22&source=bl&ots=Vozbc-Ysu7&sig=ACfU3U0UDHEFmdXxL07Ty6C8NPT-a9HBfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjmo-yj_DmAhUGip4KHfmeC_4Q6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22It%20had%20happened%20in%20a%20country%20meadow%20while%20he%20was%20at%20work%20on%20composing%20a%20new%20song.%20The%20words%20resisted%20for%20a%20while%22&f=false)** by *Ingo Swann*.

Dan Meriweather is the rock star who has psychic abilities. From the book:

> It had happened in a country meadow while he was at work on composing a new song. The words resisted for a while, then fell into place. And with their ordering had come the music. He was pleased and sang it, tentatively, to a flower nearby, a small one with three delicate, pointed creamy petals. When he finished singing it, there was an echo. At least so he had thought. But it persisted and did not die away. Reverberations in his guitar strings? But they had quieted. It was the flower trembling, singing back
>   to him. And then he understood that whatever else that special awareness might
>   be, it had ears beyond ears and eyes beyond eyes. That had been several years
>   ago, but the delicate sound lingered in his mental corridors. He had been
>   curious enough to look the plant's name up in a wild-flower guide: trillium.

[image: Cover of *Star Fire*]

Comment: It amuses me that the trillium was found in meadow, when it is a forest plant.  Research FTW!

Comment: @DavidW I'm amazed his psychic powers didn't find that error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingo_Swann